# Neither Equals nor GetHashCode get called on IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, linq, iequalitycomparer

I'm comparing two `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` with my own `IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, object>>` implementation, but neither GetHashCode nor Equals method get called.

Here's my own IEqualityComparer implementation.

```
public class TestEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, object>>
{
    public bool Equals(Dictionary<string, object> a, Dictionary<string, object> b)
    {
        return true; // breakpoint here
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<string, object> obj)
    {
        return 0; // breakpoint here
    }
}
```

And here's a actual comparing code.

```
var a = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
var b = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

a.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["id"] = 1, ["msg"] = "aaaaa" });
a.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["id"] = 2, ["msg"] = "bbbbb" });
a.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["id"] = 3, ["msg"] = "ccccc" });

b.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["id"] = 1, ["msg"] = "zzzzz" });
b.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["id"] = 2, ["msg"] = "bbbbb" });
b.Add(new Dictionary<string, object> { ["id"] = 4, ["msg"] = "ddddd" });

var except = a.Except(b, new TestEqualityComparer());
```

When I ran the above code, breakpoints never got triggered.
What's the problem?

Comment: Try switching *optimization off*: it seems that both methods are *inlined*: optimizer can see that both methods return *constant* that's why the final code doesn't call the methods at all.

Comment: Try calling `ToList()` on result of `Except` to force materialization.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko It is disabled already.

Comment: @orhtej2 It turns out that was the problem here. Can you post it as an anwer instead of comment so I can approve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [LINQ uses deferred execution](http://blog.somewhatabstract.com/2015/06/01/linq-deferred-execution/) the contents of `except` collection will not be determined unless you decide to iterate over it, hence no calls to your `IEqualityComparer`.

To force evaluation of your `Except` statement you can either iterate over it with `foreach` or append `ToList/ToArray` to your statement, like so:

```
var except = a.Except(b, new TestEqualityComparer()).ToList(); // ToList forces processing of LINQ query
```