# IEqualityComparer is not called on Distinct

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, lambda

Why the duplicate in the following list is not being filtered:

```
var distinctValues = new[]
{
    new Tuple<int[], int[]>(new[] {1, 2}, new[] {3}),
    new Tuple<int[], int[]>(new[] {2, 3}, new[] {5}),
    new Tuple<int[], int[]>(new[] {1, 2}, new[] {3})
}.Distinct(new TupleEnumerableComparer<int[]>());
```

My complete code is following:

```
public class TupleEnumerableComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T, T>> where T : IEnumerable
{
    public bool Equals(Tuple<T, T> left, Tuple<T, T> right)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        {
            return true;
        }
    
        if (left is null || right is null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        return left.Item1.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(right.Item1.Cast<object>()) &&
           left.Item2.Cast<object>().SequenceEqual(right.Item2.Cast<object>())
    }
    
    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<T, T> obj)
    {
        var valuesInObject = obj.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(property => property.GetValue(obj));

        var hash = new HashCode();
        foreach (var value in valuesInObject)
        {
            hash.Add(value);
        }

        return hash.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

I've putted the breakpoints in both GetHashCode and Equals in the above class but none of them were picked up. What did I do wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Call ToList or something equivalent on the result so that the enumerable gets enumerated.

Comment: `Distinct`- as all linq-methods - does not actually return a *collection*, but just an *iterator*, which you can execute using `foreach`, `ToArray` or `ToList`. Until you do so, none of your code will be executed. That´s what we call **deferred execution**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Neither Equals nor GetHashCode get called on IEqualityComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267473/neither-equals-nor-gethashcode-get-called-on-iequalitycomparer)

Answer (score 0):

As [@Ralf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777522/ralf) [pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66652371/iequalitycomparer-is-not-called-on-distinct/66652472#comment117824139_66652371), the enumerable wasn't enumerated:

> Call ToList or something equivalent on the result so that the
> enumerable gets enumerated.